# Determine how long a file has been open

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Is it possible in linux to determine how long a file has been open for? I have a process I suspect is performing long running operations on some files, but I'm unsure how to check.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not the answer you are looking for, but `ps` has **lstart** as a standard format specifier.

> lstart      STARTED   time the command started.  See also bsdstart, start, start_time, and stime.

So in your case `ps -eo pid,lstart,cmd` could indicate how long a specific command is running.

```
-e            Select all processes.
-o format     User-defined format.
```